# how to assign crc check in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pycrypto

I am creating a nurse call monitor system using raspberry pi. in my project i have assigned a switch to every bed and in every room i will assign a pic micro controller. the switches from the bed will send signal to pic of that room. And the pic's will send signal to raspberry pi at the nurse station through xbee.all this module is done. Now i want to assign a crc in my raspberry pi python programme. to check what ever the pic's send is received correctly or not. if data is not correct pic will resend. Also want to assign address to every pic. How to do that. please help.

My code is something like that--

```
xbee=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate=9600  ,timeout=1.0)
receiveddata=StringVar()
receiveddata= xbee.readline().strip()

if receiveddata:
    if receiveddata== "ok" :
        monitor()
        print receiveddata
        address=address+'1'
        call()
        service()
        message()
```

how to assign crc in this base model.